# Correct usage of Convertfrom-json

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to make use of some data I have captured from an API that is in JSON format but struggling to make use of it in any real meaningful way. I'm not sure if the data isn't quite as expected or the issue is with the way I am handling it.

```
$result =  Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -URI "http://vwhmcs.com/includes/api.php" -Body $Body
```

This is the API call, from here the data I need is in $result.content and looks like this

```
{"result":"success","totalresults":2,"startnumber":0,"numreturned":2,"clients":{"client":[{"id":2,"firstname":"Edward","lastname":"Franks","companyname":"","email":"EdwardFranks@mail.com","datecreated":"2018-10-09","groupid":0,"status":"Inactive"},{"id":1,"firstname":"Frank","lastname":"Tighe","companyname":"U32 Consultation","email":"frank@u32.co.uk","datecreated":"2018-10-08","groupid":0,"status":"Active"}]}}
```

Which is valid JSON (I validated it.) to try and make this usable I am doing

```
$result = ($result.content | convertfrom-json)
```

Which on the surface seems to work

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $result


result       : success
otalresults : 2
startnumber  : 0
numreturned  : 2
clients      : @{client=System.Object[]}
```

However, if I try and navigate this data, I can see that it isn't fully parsed.

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $result.clients | ft -AutoSize -Wrap

client                                                                                                                                                                                       
------                                                                                                                                                                                       
{@{id=2; firstname=Edward; lastname=Franks; companyname=; email=EdwardFranks@mail.com; datecreated=2018-10-09; groupid=0; status=Inactive}, @{id=1; firstname=Frank; lastname=Tighe;companyname=U32 Consultation; email=frank@u32.co.uk; datecreated=2018-10-08; groupid=0; status=Active}}
```

Now I can see this data is not in Valid JSON format, but if you check earlier in the data it was. The convertfrom-json function has removed the speech marks from it, which suggests to me, the data was fine but I am calling this function incorrectly.

Can anyone tell me how to do this correctly?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your data or the conversion. `$results.clients` is a nested object with a property `client` that contains an array with more objects. Try `$result.clients.client[0]`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly right, Thanks so much.

Comment: when working with APIs I recommend using `Invoke-RestMethod` instead of `Inoke-WebRequest`. With `Invoke-RestMethod` the data is automatically parsed and you don't have to run `ConvertFrom-Json` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Seems what you need is

```
$TEST.clients.client | ft
```

The JSON is

```
"clients":{
    "client":[
        {Client 1 Information Here},
        {Client 2 Information Here}
```

"clients" is a Hash Table **{** with

"client" is a array **[** of

"{Client Information}" Hash Tables